# advantage of ternary operator over if else?

Tags: c

is there any performance or memory wise advantage of using ternary operator over if else (or vice versa)?
For example a case below:

```
int x=0, y=1, z=2, a=0;
a= x ? y : z;
```

alternative:

```
if ( x != 0 ){
    a = y;
}else{
    a = z;
}
```

Comment: notice and compare code length

Comment: There is most likely no performance advantage and certainly no memory usage advantage.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan why is code length important? If the performance is the same, then code length is unimportant compared to human readability

Comment: @DavidA.French ternary operator is much succinct than 'if' /'else'  and for simple expression it better readable and oneliner. Readability counts above performance

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan readability is subjective. For many people, the if/else statement is more readable. 

And you didn't make your point based on readability. You said code length. Code length=/=readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the disassembly of both approaches, they're generally the same on any modern compiler I know of. The ternary operator is just a compact form of writing the same thing.

Here's an example using gcc 4.2.1 on Mac OS X:

With if/else:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z;

if (x < y)
{
    z = 3;
}
else
{
    z = 4;
}
```

With the ternary operator:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = (x <  y) ? 3 : 4;
```

If you run gcc -S test.c on both of these, you get this assembly for the if/else version:

```
    movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -20(%rbp), %ecx
    cmpl    %ecx, %eax
    jge LBB1_2
    movl    $3, -12(%rbp)
    jmp LBB1_3
LBB1_2:
    movl    $4, -12(%rbp)
```

and this for the ternary operator version:

```
    movl    $1, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -16(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -16(%rbp), %ecx
    cmpl    %ecx, %eax
    jge LBB1_2
    movl    $3, -20(%rbp)
    jmp LBB1_3
LBB1_2:
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)
```

The register offsets are different, but functionally, the code does the same thing. It adds two literals to two different registers, then compares and jumps based on the result of the comparison.

Comment: When I have a simple `printf` statement as the meat of the if/else, the compiler converts it to `_puts`, whereas in the ternary it uses `_printf`. Any idea why there's a difference? I'm using gcc 4.5.0.

Answer (score 4):

Compilers are generally smart enough to optimize both into same instructions. It is better idea to use ternary operator without assuming compiler optimization.

Answer (score 2):

On any modern compiler there is generally no difference between those two.

Therefore it is only a question of readabilty and maintainability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The only "advantage" is that you can use the ternary operator in an expression (eg. function arguments), making for terser code. using an `if`, you'd duplicate the full expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever is most readable in your particular circumstances.

Worry about efficiency only when you have measured that you have a performance problem.

In all likelihood, the compiler will generate the same code.