# Strange things happen with bool?

Tags: c

Why with variable `a` do I need to use the symbol `=`, but with variable `b` GCC tells me to use `==`? Should they all being used with `=`, am I wrong or what? If I use a normal `if`, this thing doesn't happen.

P.S: I know about the `<stdbool.h>`.

Thanks everyone.

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1

typedef int BOOL;

int main()
{
    BOOL a;
    BOOL b;

    int num = 21; // random number

    (num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b = TRUE;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to start from the very beginning. = and == are completely different an unrelated. == is used for comparisons, and = is used for assignments. And defining FALSE to be 1 will screw up everything.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question, i know what = and == are for, i m just telling why this thing happen with inline operator, with a normal if i don't need to use == for b.

Comment: By the way you can use `stdbool.h` and `bool a = false`. You don't need need define & typedef anymore.

Comment: define FALSE 1???

Comment: Please also read [Advantage of ternary operator over if else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767458/advantage-of-ternary-operator-over-if-else?noredirect=1&lq=1) and see that the answer is None. It just makes code harder to understand - like in this case.

Comment: `gcc -Wall` doesn't complain anything about either version. Perhaps this is not exactly the same code that you wanted to ask about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This type of syntax is called a ternary operator. They are generally used to perform simple expressions, or assign things to ONE variable based on a condition, rather than handle assignment logic with two variables.

This is why you can't have both `a = TRUE` and `b = TRUE` in the ternary operator. You should only have values or things that return values in there.

e.g.

```
BOOL result = (num == 21 ? TRUE : FALSE);
BOOL a = result;
BOOL b = !result;
```

Read more on ternary operators on [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Also, slightly unrelated to your actual question, but still an issue you should fix; [Lee Daniel Crocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192494/lee-daniel-crocker) made a good point. `FALSE` shouldn't really be defined as `1`, as it is usually defined as `0` in most programming contexts. `TRUE` is defined as any number other than `0`, i.e. `!FALSE`. Hence, try doing this to define your TRUE and FALSE:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you please accept the answer?

Comment: If this post is incorrect, please consider leaving a comment on how it could be improved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky at first. But there is a simple reason why GCC complains.

`(num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b = TRUE;`

Here, the colon operator takes precedence over equal to operator. So effectivey, this statement is evaluated as

`((num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b) = TRUE;`

which in turn is the same as

`TRUE = TRUE;`

So the compiler rightly complains that lvalue required as left operand of assignment. However, if you use parenthesis to correct the affinity, it won't complain.

`(num == 21) ? (a = TRUE) : (b = TRUE);` //No compiler error

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to

```
((num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b) = TRUE;
```

Thus, you are assigning to the result of expression, but not to the variable. Therefore compiler demands `==` operator.

Use

```
(num == 21) ? a = TRUE : (b = TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better code using `stdbool.h` library. `=` & `==` are direfferent ! The first one is used for asignation and the second one for a comparing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){

bool a = false;
bool b = false;

int num = 21; // random nr lol

bool result = (num == 21) ? true : false;
a = result;
b = !result;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `bool result = (num == 21);` and skip the ternary operator?

Comment: Yes it is the same, it was just to fit with the example :)

Comment: @BoPersson did you put -1 just because of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to do this:

```
(num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b = TRUE;
```

The syntax is invalid due to operator precedence.  The ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the expression above is the same as:

```
((num == 21) ? a = TRUE : b) = TRUE;
```

This is invalid syntax because you can't have an expression like this on the left side of an assignment.

You need to add parenthesis to get the behavior you want.

```
(num == 21) ? a = TRUE : (b = TRUE);
```